# Unable to start Windows container: HNS file used by another process

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am attempting to build an a using docker-compose in which 2 containers are connected to each other using the following network:

```
networks:
  nd:
    external:
      name: nat
```

Recently, I've started to receive the following error while starting the application:

```
 ERROR: app: Cannot start service app: failed to create endpoint app on
 network nat: HNS failed with error : The process cannot access the file 
 because it is being used by another process.
 ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

I've tried using Microsoft's [tool](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/Virtualization-Documentation/tree/live/windows-server-container-tools/CleanupContainerHostNetworking) to clean up networking, and I've removed and reinstalled Docker, but the error persists.

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem because I was mapping ports to host ports that were in use.  I daresay there are other reasons but hopefully this is yours!

Answer (score 0):

check if you have been using a Linux container, it wont be listed in the command "docker ps -a". they have different lists and different vm.

Answer (score 0):

in my case host machine port was in use. I changed it and was resolved

Answer (score 0):

This is how I fixed my issue in windows
Control Panel -> Network and Internet -> Network Connections
I had 2 Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet adapters enabled. Disabling one of them fixed my issue.
It seems as if the other one was using the hns.data file, which is why the other gave that error, try it. Hope it helps some one else ;)